# Symfony entity type can not set select value, placeholder was selected

Tags: symfony

I am calling entity to provide drop down options. I set a place holder value. I tried setting the data value, but regardless placeholder value is alway tag with selected.

My PostFormType:

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

```
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array( 'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control'
        )))
        ->add('price', TextType::class, array( 'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control'
        )))
        ->add('artist', EntityType::class, [
            'data'=>2,
            'placeholder'=>'Choose Artist',
            'class'=>Artist::class,
            'choice_label'=>'artist',
            'query_builder'=> function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('artist')
                    ->orderBy('artist.artist', 'ASC');
            },

            'empty_data'  => null,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control'
            )
        ])

        ->add('userId', HiddenType::class )
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array( 'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control'
        )))
        ->add('purchaseDate','date')
        ->add('id',HiddenType::class)
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't configure `data` for property `artist` if it has to be modified by user in the form.

In case you want to set the default value of a new Entity. Even if you do, the change from UI form will not affect as the `data` attribute will reset the value to `2` as provided after submit.

You can always use `Constructor` of the relevant `Entity` to set any default value.

But, as `artist` is a referenced property. You should do it in `Controller` before you build the form.

```
$artist = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Artist")->find(2);
$entity->setArtist($artist)
// Load the form here. The default value automatically set in the form
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using symfony 6.3, and could solve it with the following modifications:

**First:** while adding artist to form:

1. Set `mapped: true`
2. Remove `value: 2`, as this will reset your artist field value to 2 each time is form is rendered, regardless of your submitted value previously
3. Set `'choice_value' => fn($c) => $c,` to tell use the entity artist as the choice value

**Second:** to convert the entity artist to a scalar value, implement `__toString()` in your artist model

**Third:** add a view transformer to transform the ID of artist to artist entity once form is submitted:

```
        $builder->get('artist')
            ->addViewTransformer(
                new CallbackTransformer(
                    function (?string $modelData): ?Artist {
                        if ($modelData === null) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        return $this->artistRepository->find((int)$modelData);
                    },
                    function ($formData) {
                        return $formData;
                    },
                )
            );
```

**Forth:**: While creating the form in your controller, pass in the submitted value, suppose you form's method is `GET`:

```
        $queryParameters = $request->query->all();
        $searchForm = $this->createForm(ArtistType::class, $queryParameters);
        $searchForm->handleRequest($request);
```